# Change the encoding of %21 etc. to character

Tags: php, encoding, urlencode

I'm working on a tool that produces images from user input with different font options. The problem I'm having at the minute is the class I use to create these images uses $_GET to retrieve the user input. The user input looks like `urlencode($text)` which produces %21 for ! etc instead of the character. urldecode() doesn't seem to do the trick.

`$text = isset(urldecode($_GET['text'])) ? $_GET['text']:'';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are wrapping `isset` on the wrong thing,

```
$text = isset($_GET['text']) ? urldecode($_GET['text']) : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning `urldecode($_GET['text'])` to `$text` variable. You are checking if `urldecode($_GET['text'])` is set, and then assigning `$_GET['text']`.

Try

```
$text = isset($_GET['text']) ? urldecode($_GET['text']) : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that `urldecode($_GET['text'])` can sometimes take a NULL value, so use the `isset()` before to determine whether a variable is set and is not NULL. if you try like this:

```php
$text = isset($_GET['text']) ? $_GET['text']:'';
$text = urldecode($text);
```

It will work.

---

`bool isset ( mixed $var [, mixed $... ] )`: In this case, `$var` is the variable to be checked and isn't value, so you couldn't use a value like `urldecode($_GET['text'])` or string for `isset()` as a parameter, include `empty()`.

Thank `@Stano` very much for his comments, his code is useful:

Comment: I understood, I am wrong. I turned on computer, You are right, `$x` is set forever either `$_GET['text']` isn't set.